# Make a number increment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have this static code:

```
  %a#carousel-selector-0.thumbnail
              %img{:src => "http://placehold.it/170x100&text=one"}/
          %li.span2
            %a#carousel-selector-1.thumbnail
              %img{:src => "http://placehold.it/170x100&text=two"}/
          %li.span2
            %a#carousel-selector-2.thumbnail
              %img{:src => "http://placehold.it/170x100&text=three"}/
          %li.span2
            %a#carousel-selector-3.thumbnail
              %img{:src => "http://placehold.it/170x100&text=four"}/
          %li.span2
            %a#carousel-selector-4.thumbnail
              %img{:src => "http://placehold.it/170x100&text=five"}/
          %li.span2
            %a#carousel-selector-5.thumbnail
              %img{:src => "http://placehold.it/170x100&text=six"}/
```

This is my each loop to make it dynamic from the db

```
- @house.attachments.each do |a|
  = link_to(image_tag(a.file.url), :id => "carousel-selector-{number}", :class => "thumbnail")
```

How can i make the {number} increment ? Like in the static example?

Comment: `:id => "carousel-selector-{$number += 1}"` assuming you have `$number = 0` set before loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
- @house.attachments.each_with_index do |a,i|
  = link_to(image_tag(a.file.url), :id => "carousel-selector-#{i}", :class => "thumbnail")
```

Comment: @BachanSmruty I think he also wants `0` if not you will are right